# is there a way to track my navigation after using jquery to display it in other pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nav

hi guys i was trying to link my nav bar on multiple pages using Jquery and after doing so the pages display the nav bar but the navigation bar does not load the javascript code , anyone who knows how to fix this please help me :) .

```
    <script>
    $.get("nav.html", function(data) {
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    });
    </script>
```

and the nav bar should use main.js to display its cursor/tracker below is the image

man.js

```
    const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId),
    bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
    headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // show navbar
    nav.classList.toggle('show')
    // change icon
    toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
    // add padding to body
    bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    // add padding to header
    headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    })
    }
    }

    showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

    /*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====*/
    const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

    function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classList.add('active')
    }
    }
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))
```

somebody help